# Vue JS2 find array value by id

Tags: vue.js

How can i get the value by id from a array in vue js? Many thanks with solution

```
list = [
    {
        "name": "Apple",
        "id": 1,
    },
    {
        "name": "Orange",
        "id": 2,
    }
]
watch: {
    food: function (val) {
        //Get food name by val(id)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method, which *returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function*:

```js
var food = list.find(food => food.id === val)
var name = food ? null : food.name
```

```js
let list = [
    {
        "name": "Apple",
        "id": 1,
    },
    {
        "name": "Orange",
        "id": 2,
    }
]

console.log(
  list.find(food => food.id === 1).name
)
```