# find object values in array Vue Javascript Vuex?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js, vuex

I have a value that I need to compare to the values in an object.  The object is like:

```
[{"dbid":800,"MemberID":1460,"ID":1460,"Search":"TRUE","Year_Start":"2017","Year_End":2019,"Last_Name":"XXXX","First_Name":"XXX","Middle_Initial":"X","Suffix":"","Email":"","Program_Code":"CM","Pending":"","Initials":"OS","Include":"1","Exclude":"0","Authoring_Names":""}, ... ]
```

and again for 100's of names.

I want to create a search box that allows the end user to compare a name to the names in the list.  So I want to send the last name of the comparing value to a function that will return most of the information such as `First Name`, `Middle Initial`, `Last name`, `Program` etc. The comparing value may or may not be in the list.

I've look at 
[Vue JS2 find array value by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53908940/vue-js2-find-array-value-by-id)
and it's close, but I want more information than one element. Also I saw that it maybe possible to filter an object in Veux, since I store that information in there.

Answer (score 3):

To find all people with a certain last name, you should use `filter` as it's very similar to `find` only it returns multiple items in an array.

```
const found = people.filter(({ Last_Name }) => person.Last_Name == Last_Name);
```

Note that to check if no people have been found you need to check if `length == 0` because an empty array is still truthy.